# 500 Internal Server Error while using curl

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using the below code in my word press site. and i am trying change some of the functionality by calling the wcf web service in my php code. below is the code i am using which is giving me error

```
$Url = "http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc/checkUseronHealnt";
$json = "[{\"MOBILE_NO\":\"8745009403,8745009411\"}]"
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_error($curl)) {
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
} else {
    echo"Response - " . $curl_response;
}
```

Comment: `$json = "[{\"MOBILE_NO\":\"8745009403,8745009411\"}]"` semicolon is missing after this line

Answer (score 0):

`$json = "[{\"MOBILE_NO\":\"8745009403,8745009411\"}]"`
`;` is missing after this
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json));`
`json_encode` is not needed here.
And  unless there is `{` somewhere above the code you provided, last `}` is also not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`$json = "[{\"MOBILE_NO\":\"8745009403,8745009411\"}]"` - Semicolon is missing after statement

Remove extra curly bracket `{}` from the code.

Your good code is below

```
$Url ="http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc/checkUseronHealnt";
$json = "[{\"MOBILE_NO\":\"8745009403,8745009411\"}]";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json));
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl)) { 
  echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl); 
}
else {
  echo"Response - ".$curl_response;
}
```